# HTML action with multiple targets

Tags: html, forms, action, frame, target

I'm trying to make a very simple html tool. I'm a beginner with html, btw.
It should have one form in a frame with one action, one textbox, one submit button. But, once you click that submit button, it should do that action in all (12) other frames.

It only works in one frame when I put in `target="2"`, for example.

My form looks like this:

```
 <form action="the action is here" target="2" >
  Code 1:<br><input name="code0" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" id="code">
 <input type="submit" name="Name">
</form>
```

My frameset looks like this:

```
    <frameset cols="25%,25%,25%,*" name="0">

  <frame src="frame1.html" name="1">


  <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%,*">
  <frame src="" name="2">
  <frame src="" name="3">
  <frame src="" name="4">
  <frame src="" name="5">

  </frameset>
  <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%,*">
  <frame src="" name="6">
  <frame src="" name="7">
  <frame src="" name="8">
  <frame src="" name="9">

  </frameset>

  <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%,*">
  <frame src="" name="10">
  <frame src="" name="11">
  <frame src="" name="12">
  <frame src="" name="13">

  </frameset>
</frameset>
<noframes>
```

How can I put in multiple targets?

I can't change or view anything about the action, that's something external.
At first I made 12 forms like this, each for one frame. It works but I think there must be a better solution than having people input the same thing 12 times and click all submit buttons.

Thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do such things in HTML. The results of form data handling will appear in one browsing context only, e.g. in a frame. To make them appear in several frames would be rather odd (what good would it do to have 12 copies of the results?), and technically it would require JavaScript.